# Place landscape figure on page and in maximum available size

Tags: floats, appendices, landscape

I need to put landscape figure on a separate page of my appendix.

The Code i tried looks like this:

```
    \chapter{Appendix 1}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{Figure 1}}
    \caption{Figure 1} \cite{Test} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\myfigures{Fig. 1} 
\clearpage
```

But Latex will throw the figure on a separate page, leaving the page with the chapter heading empty. Is there a way to automatically scale the figure, so it used all space available without being pushed on the next page?

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you presumably know how much space your chapter heading takes up so just change `height=\textheight,` to be a suitable smaller value, but you seem to be using the wrong values, you scale the height of the image to `\textheight` but then rotate it so that length is trying to fit into the width of the page, I assume you want

```
    \rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics[width=.7\textheight]{Figure 1}}
```

assuming you want to leave 30% of the text height for your heading, adjust to suit your document style.